# Get JSON values for a specific name using a Windows batch script

Tags: json, windows, batch-file

I have a JSON file, `demo.json`, like this:

```json
{"status":true,"code":300,"msg":"6e8987cfb05d647c2c0164043b25de7420230522111435","data":[{"ip":"1.2.3.4","sign":"dd9bde86cc8d360c7a346ad2611a19b9"},{"ip":"5.6.7.8","sign":"2f5ad72febe3e0f49354ef0db1edc642"}]
}
```

How can I get the IP list with a Windows batch script?

Comment: We are not here to write code to order, tell you what to write,or give you reference links to other places which may. Please do your own research and write some code, before seeking help with that code. I would also strongly advise that you consider using PowerShell instead, or as well. The 'batch' parser cannot understand JSON, PowerShell can.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't. At least not with a Windows default tools. Is it impossible? No.

1. Windows batch scripts
   The naive method is to parse the text, but I don't recommend it. It's slow, inefficient, difficult to scale and not reliable code-wise, not to mention a hell to maintain when you need to update or fix the code.

A proper way is to use a command line tool, unfortunately, I don't know of any built-in tool that can parse json. However, we can use external tools and integrate them in the windows batch shell. One such utility is [./jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Pros: `./jq` is cross-platform, so if you will need to move to some other OS, it won't have much of an impact.

Cons: First of all, it's an external tool, so that means you need to get it from a third party. Secondly, if it's for work, chances are company security policies won't let you download exe files or run unknown executables. If it's for a personal project which you share with others they might be cautious about running an unknown exe that does god-knows-what (from their point of view).

Example: `jq-win64.exe -r "."data" | .[] ."ip""  test.json`

2. Of course, if you want to align with how Microsoft wants users/admins to automate Windows, you have the option of using PowerShell. It has built-in support for XML and JSON.

Pros: It's fast, efficient and built-in, not to mention it has support for tons of things.

Cons: If it's for work, security policies won't let you download exe files or run PS scripts.

Example: `(Get-Content .\test.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).data.ip`

3. VBScript

Similar to #1. You can use [vbsEdit](https://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/toolkit/json.asp) or maybe some repositories on GitHub (such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/douglascrp/26477fa0c523186b55705890a97b9821#file-vbscript-class-for-json-encode-decode)). Note: I haven't tried either. And similar to #1, I don't recommend this approach.

Edit:
4. The user [Compo](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) also recommends combining 1 and 2 to launch PS from a batch file in a comment.

Example: `@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content '.\test.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).data.ip"`

Comment: You don't need a PS script for this task, you can run a PowerShell command directly from a batch file, without the need to modify security policies. The only restriction would be if your admin has specifically disallowed your permission to execute PowerShell. They are much less likely to have done that, than to have restricted you from downloading and running other tools too. ```@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content '.\test.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).data.ip"```.

Comment: How to receive the IP list in batch script, since there needs additional process for each IP

Comment: Do it in a `for` loop @aqiao. For example: ```@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content '.\test.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).data.ip" 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%G```. Obviously you'd change the `Echo` command to reflect whatever it is you intend to do with each result string, `%%G`.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done without external tools with [jsonextractor.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/jsonextractor.bat) :

```
jsonextractor.bat demo.json data.ip
```

Comment: Just passing by to mention it's using VBScript, not the old school batch scripting. Interesting way of using HTML support to make it work.

Comment: @TheNomad - it is jscript which also part of windows script host as vbscript.

Comment: Ah yes, I see the call now. Sorry, I admit I glanced at the syntax only. Thanks for making me double check.